# Ubuntu bash script reuse input variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep, pipe

I am trying to implement a bash script that reads input from a piped command. I want to process each line on the input and perform some processing on each line. Additionally, I want to reuse the input passed to the script. However, I have noticed that I am unable to reuse the input. Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    percentage=$(echo $line | awk 'printf $1')
    # perform some processing using the total i.e. percentage/total*100
done
```

This script is to be executed like this:

```
cat data.txt | grep "status" | ./myscript.sh
```

Sample data is:

```
1 STATUS
2 AUTHORISED
11 SENT
```

If the script is modified to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
total=$(cut -f1 $1)
echo $total
while read $input
do
    percentage=$(echo $line | awk 'printf $1')
     # perform some processing using the total i.e. percentage/total*100
done
```

This script only ouputs the total and the while loop is not executed.

Multiple piped commands are required for this task, as this script will be used by many things so that it is kept generic and reusable. How can this be achived without storing the contents to a file?

Sample Input:

```
1 STATUS
2 AUTHORISED
11 SENT
```

Total would be 14. So each item i.e. 1/14*100,2/14*100 and 11/14*100.

Comment: You have used `cut -f1 $1`, but you are not passing anything over command line. So, the command becomes just `cut -f1` and thus takes `stdin` as file-name. Since all the `stdin` is exhausted, `while read` fails for the first `read` and hence the loop is never executed.

Comment: Besides, what were you trying with `while read $input`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am trying to process each line by printing it and performing some calculations such as percentages etc. The command grep "status" is an example. It could be grep S where that would return all the 3 items.

Comment: Provide sample input (6-7 lines) and expected output.

Comment: Just added this information. Please check.

Comment: @RajivJain - there's a big difference between `while read line` and `while read $input`. One of them has a dollar sign.

Comment: Why are you opposed to storing the data in a file and reading it twice?  If you redirect to a temporary file and delete that file when you are done, there is almost zero chance of the data ever hitting a physical medium outside of ram on any operating system built in the last 15 years.  If you really want to be sure, put TMPDIR on a ram disk.  Are you worried about the IO performance, or are you concerned about leaking secure data?

Comment: I don't understand your examples.  If your input is as you show, then `grep status` will produce no output.  `grep -i status` would produce one line of output...but in that case what are you summing and what is the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script won't work because your $1 arg is empty.

Use xargs to get the argument instead of using it as stdin. Also since the output could be multi line you can use -0 on xargs to use the null delimiter.

```
> cat data.txt | grep -i 'status' | xargs -0 ./myscript.sh
```

Then you need to actually calculate the total, I did that here using awk because I was being lazy, but there is probably an easier way.

You can then read input line by line using read.

I edited the script to work for me in a test environment, see below:

```
#!/bin/bash                                              
input="$1"                                               
echo "$input"                                            
total=$(echo "$input" | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}') 
echo "$input" | while read line; do                      
      if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then                          
          num=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')           
          percentage=$((100 * num / total))              
          echo "$percentage"                             
      fi                                                 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a+=$1; next;} {print $1*100/a;}' data.txt data.txt
```

For the `grep` operation part:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if ($0 ~ pattern) a+=$1; next;} {if ($0 ~ pattern) print $1*100/a;}' pattern=STATUS data.txt data.txt
```

If the input is not in a file, we can cache it in `awk` itself.

```
awk '{a+=$1; b[NR]=$1;} END {for(i in b) print b[i]*100/a;}' data.txt

awk '$0 ~ pattern {a+=$1; b[NR]=$1;} END {for(i in b) print b[i]*100/a;}'  pattern=STATUS data.txt

some_command | awk '$0 ~ pattern {a+=$1; b[NR]=$1;} END {for(i in b) print b[i]*100/a;}'  pattern=STATUS
```

Comment: This will not work for my needs. I have multiple piped commands that are fed into the script. So the grep is already done prior to arriving into the script. Any other solution? I want to reuse the input, into a variable. That is what I originally asked for in this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform arithmetic based on the total, you need to know that total before performing your arithmetic. So you need two loops -- one to read the data and add up the total, and the other to process that data based on the total.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Prepare our variables
declare total=0
declare -a data=()
declare -a newdata=()

# Collect the array data and build our total...
while read value text; do
    data+=($value)
    ((total+=$value))
done

# Process the array, populating a new array with the results.
for i in "${!data[@]}"; do
    newdata[$i]=$(( 100 * ${data[$i]} / $total ))
done

# Show our results
declare -p data
declare -p newdata
```

Remember that bash only supports integer math, so it's important to use `100 * $val1 / $val2` rather than `$val1 / $val2 * 100`.  If you want greater precision, consider using external tools like `bc` or `dc` instead of doing your math in bash alone.

My results with the script above on the sample data in your question:

```
$ testme.sh < testme.txt
declare -a data=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="11")
declare -a newdata=([0]="7" [1]="14" [2]="78")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a temporary file.  But it's easy enough to store the data in memory.

(This script assumes you are totaling column one, and that column one in each line is a count of data points matching the status in column 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

data=$(cat)  # Read all of the input and store it
total=$(echo "$data" | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}')
echo "$data" | while read count status; do
        printf "%s:\t%2.2f%%\n" \
        "$status" "$(echo "20k$count $total/100*p" | dc)"
done
```